# installede xampp and getting error even the url correct

Tags: php, localhost

I installed xampp in my system and I am getting the phpmyadmin also but when I am trying to access the file in htdocs I am getting error.In localhost I am trying to access index.php file which is a login page.After that I am trying to login in  that page by entering the mail id and password then I am getting the "error 404" and "object not found".Please help me.The urls are correct but still i am getting error.

Comment: We cannot help with that little information. Keep in mind that we cannot see over your shoulder... So: what does your http servers error log file say?

Comment: error 404 is thrown it can not find mentioned page. check in that aspect if you have given correct address/url in action in the form

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Perhaps you can add more details, to explain better the most important parts of your question and show a part of your data. Have a read of [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for more information.

Comment: prasanna puttaswamy the url is correct still i am getting error